# Changing the dimensions of Childbrowswer plugin for Phonegap in iOS

Tags: cordova

I am using the Childbrowser plugin with Phonegap on iOS to do facebook connect with in my app.  It all works but when the Childbrowser window opens it takes the full screen.  How can I get it to just pop up in a small window in a corner, do the work then quit?

Answer (score 2):

I needed the same thing...

Since I couldn't find ready-to-use solution here, I decided to do it myself... I see this is very old post so I guess you already found a solution, but just in case you haven't and someone else might find it useful and save a couple of minutes :)

NOTE: my target is **iPad only**, so I opted for UIPopoverViewController, for an iPhone there were other ViewControllers that could be used, but the idea would be the same...

What I did is edited `ChildBrowserCommand.h` and added:

```
#define POPOVER_WIDTH 400
#define POPOVER_HEIGHT 300

@interface ChildBrowserCommand : PGPlugin <ChildBrowserDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate>  {
    ChildBrowserViewController* childBrowser;
    UIPopoverController *popover;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) ChildBrowserViewController *childBrowser;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popover;
```

Also, I edited `ChildBrowserCommand.m`, synthetized popover, and changed:

```
//[ cont presentModalViewController:childBrowser animated:YES ];
```

with:

```
if (popover == NULL)
{
    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:childBrowser];
    [popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(POPOVER_WIDTH, POPOVER_HEIGHT) animated:YES];
    popover.delegate = self;
}
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:cont.view.bounds inView:cont.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
```

and also added dismiss line:

```
-(void) onClose
{
    NSString* jsCallback = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ChildBrowser._onClose();",@""];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallback];

    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Finally, I removed (commented out) dismissModal from `ChildBrowserViewController.m` (btw, kind of wrong place to have it there in the first place):

```
-(void)closeBrowser
{   
    if(delegate != NULL)
    {
        [delegate onClose];     
    }

    //[super dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

As a result, ChildBrowser opens in UIPopoverViewController with specified size (and no arrows in my case, if you want some, just specify `UIPopoverArrowDirection`), dismisses nicely when finished and/or when clicked outside of the popover window...

Best Regards,
Srdjan